# How do I change font family of title in html?

Tags: html, font-family

I learned to change the font family of text in the body by doing `<p style="font-family:;></p>`, but how would I do it for the title? Also, is there a way to fixing a font family for the entire document?

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY wanted to set the entire document you could use the below noting that more specific selectors will over-ride it unless you specify !important (though I strongly recommend against using !important on a selector this vast):

```
body {
    font: normal 10px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use (html{}) in your style.css Therefore, it will apply to any element inside your (HTML). unless you explicitly specify otherwise.

Further on the matter, on the example, I gave you if you are to remove the child1 or child2 font-family it will default to whatever is in the body section if you are to remove the font-family from the body it will default to the HTML.

[

```css
/*Change the font style on the Entire Document */
html{
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;  
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: Gray;
}

/*Change on the Body*/
body{
   font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;  
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align:center;
}
/*Change on a specific elements*/
#container .child1{
  font-family:  cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;   
  text-align:center;
  background-color: blue;
}

#container .child2{
  font-family: cursive;
  
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  text-align:center;
}

footer{
 font-family:  'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>I am the Header</p>
</header>

<div id="container">
    <div class="child1">
    <p>I am a Body Child</p>
    </div>

 <div class="child2">
      <p>I am another body Child</p>
    </div>
</div>

<footer> I am the Footer</footer>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwUqN.png)

Answer (score -3):

You can code a style element within the head element your HTML file to apply styles globally throughout your document:

```
<style>
title {
font-family:; /* usually the name of your font goes here */
}
</style>
```

Comment: the title is typically only part of the browser, not intended to be displayed as part of the DOM, and thus can not be styled unless you are explicitly setting the display to be visible.